# Redirect traffic of an interface to a socks5 proxy

Tags: networking, network-interface, proxy, socks5-proxy

I've got a VM that I create using [virt manager](https://virt-manager.org/). The program creates virtual interfaces like:

```
$ ip addr
4: virbr2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:7a:2e:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global virbr2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

in which the VM uses to connect to the internet. How can I redirect all this interface to a socks5 proxy, like a tor proxy running on 127.0.0.1:9050? So any internet traffic from the vm will be forcefully redirected through tor? (or if there is a simpler solution...)